# Prevent chrome from stealing focus

Tags: google-chrome, intellij-idea, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to prevent the chrome dev tools from stealing the focus if you stop the debugger / reach a breakpoint?

I'm debugging with intellij js debug and chrome is stealing its focus on every step.

Comment: Gah this is pissing me off too...

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Yes. I stopped frontend developing. ;) but no

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the Chrome DevTools Settings under Preferences -> Sources, there is an option "Focus Sources panel when triggering a breakpoint". Disabling this option seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

That is really annoying, my kind of solution is to set the size of the Chrome window very small and then navigate using the Chrome Debugger Shortcuts (F10, F11, F8) and not the WebStorm/IntelliJ ones (F8, F7, F9), then it kind of works. Chrome stays in focus, but it is small and you see it stepping normally in the WebStorm.